# Passwordless encryption of flash drive

Tags: ubuntu, encryption, flash-memory

I am using Ubuntu and I have an encrypted flash drive which synchronizes with a folder on my desktop whenever I plug it into the computer (using rsync and a systemctl service that runs the bash script doing rsync whenever this exact device is plugged in).

How could I create a passwordless encrypted flash drive that automatically unlocks once I connect it to my own desktop, so I don't have to enter the password every time?

**EDIT**

This is how I did it after the information I got from the accepted answer:

1) I created a random keyfile:

`sudo dd if=/dev/urandom of=/etc/luks/keyfile bs=1024 count=4`

2) Then I used the cryptsetup `luksAddKey` command to add it to my already encrypted flash drive (where I found the relevant uuid by using the cryptsetup `luksUUID` command)

`sudo cryptsetup -v luksAddKey /dev/disk/by-uuid/XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX /etc/luks/keyfile`

3) To ensure the device uses the keyfile instead of the password on my machine I had to create a mapper by adding the following line to `/etc/crypttab` using the UUID of the device

`my_crypt_mapper  /dev/disk/by-uuid/XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX  /etc/luks/keyfile  luks`

Comment: How is the drive encrypted? It must accept a keyfile, right? You've got some other method to ensure the keyfile is secure, like your home or system drive is encrypted?

Comment: The flash drive is just an USB stick which I encrypted using Ubuntu's native cryptsetup package. This prompts me for a password whenever I plug the drive into my desktop. I want it to unlock automatically whenever I plug it into my machine.

Comment: Then just use `--key-file` with cryptsetup, I don't know how your rsync & systemctl is set up to do the other things automatically, but just add the keyfile decrypt command in there (if that's good enough for an answer I'll add it)

Comment: Good enough, I got it working!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using  cryptsetup, it has an option to use a key file instead of a password, so just use

```
- - k e y - f i l e
```

I don't know how your rsync & systemctl is set up to do the other things automatically, but just add the  cryptsetup --keyfile... decrypt command in there.

You might want some other method to ensure the keyfile is secure, like your home or system drive is encrypted?